# XCode 6 - iOS 8: programmatically check if view is installed

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, autolayout, size-classes

I am using class sizes in interface builder, defining slightly different designs for different sizes.

One of my view is not installed for a specific size. That works as expected, but now I would like to programmatically be able to tell if that view is installed or not. Whether it is installed or not, it looks like the view is never nil, and I can't see any isInstalled flag to check.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a great solution, but I've not found a better one yet:

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnableAndDisableViews.html) state that "A runtime object for an uninstalled view is still created. However, the view and any related constraints are not added to the view hierarchy and the view has a superview property of nil".

So a test for a valid superview works as a solution, but I've found that it has to come quite late - in `viewDidAppear`. The superviews are still nil in `viewWillAppear`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple Docs:[Installing and Uninstalling Views for a Size Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnableAndDisableViews.html)

> A runtime object for an uninstalled view is still created. However, the view and any related constraints are not added to the view hierarchy and the view has a superview property of nil. This is different from being hidden. A hidden view is in the view hierarchy along as are any related constraints.

You could check by evaluating `PossiblyUninstalledView.superView != nil`. If it is true, then the class is properly installed.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an extension to UIView and check to see if the view has a superview. If it's Installed it will return true, if it's no it will return false.

```
extension UIView {
    func isInstalled() -> Bool{
        return (self.superview != nil) ? true : false
    }
}
```